# Pdo query inserts only one name of pic

Tags: php, mysql

This code works it uploads multiple images to the folder but when it come to inserting information of the images to the database it inserts only 1 name . for any assistance I will appreciate it

```
#target folder
$target = 'image_uploads/';
  if(isset($_FILES['image_name'])===true){
      $files = $_FILES['image_name'];
      for($x = 0 ; $x < count($files['name']); $x++){
          $name = $files['name'][$x] ;
          $temp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$x];
          $move = move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$target.$name);
      }
  }
?>
<?php
try{
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tish_database;charset=utf-8','root','');
    $query="INSERT INTO tish_images(image_name)
VALUES(:image_name)";
    $insert = $con->prepare($query);
    $insert->execute(array(
                          ':image_name'=>$name));
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i m not sure but you need to define your insert query inside for loop.

Comment: True that was the only prob tahnks . Now I need a line that can rename a picture incase if another file with the same name exists

Answer (score 1):

Your `INSERT` & `execute array` statement are outside of `for` cycle.

Answer (score 0):

@Devang Rathod and @revoua . I really appreciated your help and here is the codes after your help guys 
Its working the way I want

```
<?php 
#target folder 
$target = 'image_uploads/';
  if(isset($_FILES['image_name'])===true){
  $files = $_FILES['image_name'];
  for($x = 0 ; $x < count($files['name']); $x++){
  $name = $files['name'][$x] ;
  $temp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$x];  
  $move = move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$target.$name); 
?>
<?php
try{
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tish_database;charset=utf-8','root','');
$query="INSERT INTO tish_images(image_name)
VALUES(:image_name)";
$insert = $con->prepare($query);
$insert->execute(array(
':image_name'=>$name));
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}
 } 
}
?>
```